# Storing references in Swift dictionaries

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write some Swift code that stores a collection of collections in a dictionary (so it can be easily serialized as a plist).  Simple enough in Objective-C, but I'm seeing some behaviour in Swift I don't understand.

Playgroundable example:

```
import Cocoa
typealias StringMap=Dictionary<String, String>
var collections = Dictionary<String, Array<StringMap>>();

// Add an empty "books" collection
collections["books"] = Array<StringMap>();

// Look up the books collection
var books = collections["books"] as Array<StringMap>!;

// Add an item to it
var book = ["name": "The Complete Peanuts", "author": "Charles M. Schulz"]
books.append(book);

// This is now 1
books.count

// Look up the books collection again
books = collections["books"] as Array<StringMap>!;

// This is zero
books.count
```

It seems like retrieving the books array from the dictionary is getting a copy of the array, not a reference to it.  I want a reference so I can update it.

Comment: Actually what you do in the last `books = coll...` is to assign a new instance to it which of course is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `Array` and `Dictionary` are `struct`, that is [value type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_144). When you assign it to another variable or constant, it will be copied. For example:

```
var a:[Int] = []
var b = a
b.append(42)

// a -> []
// b -> [42]
```

So, in your case, you should do all your work from `collections` variable:

```
typealias StringMap=Dictionary<String, String>

var collections = Dictionary<String, Array<StringMap>>();
collections["books"] = Array<StringMap>();

var book = ["name": "The Complete Peanuts", "author": "Charles M. Schulz"]
collections["books"]!.append(book)

collections["books"]!.count
```

Or, prepare the array, and assign to the dictionary:

```
var collections = Dictionary<String, Array<StringMap>>();

var books = Array<StringMap>();
var book = ["name": "The Complete Peanuts", "author": "Charles M. Schulz"]
books.append(book)

collections["books"] = books
```